# How to create a ListField with 2 textfield and 1 icon on each row?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, listfield

I am new on Blackberry app. development. Can you suggest some documentations about custom ListField?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achive this easily with out using a custom list field.
You just use  "drawListRow" method  class ListCallback implements ListFieldCallback.

eg:

```
private class ListCallback implements ListFieldCallback{
        public void drawListRow(ListField list, Graphics g, int index, int y,int w) {

 g.drawBitmap(0, y, mp3Bitmap.getWidth(), 50, mp3Bitmap, 0, 0);
 g.drawText(mediaTypeString,40, y, 0, w);    
 g.drawText(bitrate+" kbps", 40, y+20, 130, w);

}
```

This will create each row of ListFiled with one image and two row of text.

Answer (score 0):

One does not normally add UI objects to a list since if the list has many items the overhead would quickly consume available resources. The application is responsible for rendering the list times in a ListFieldCallback. So just set the ListField.setRowHight() to give you the room you need, then render the text and icon as you need.

Comment: I concur -- ListField in BB is not as friendly to nested UI components as say Android... If that's what you're after.

Creating a VerticalFieldManager with nested custom Fields has been successful for me.